# Difference between "full-infinitive" and "preposition + gerund-participle" in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Is there any difference between these two sentences, please?

*We went to Paris to visit the Louvre museum.

We went to Paris for visiting the Louvre museum.*

Answer (score 1):

To my ears the first sentence is fine, but the second sentence sounds wrong.

I suspect that the difference is that in the first sentence "to" is not a preposition but the first part of the infinitive of the verb "to visit". In the second sentence "for" is a preposition and should form part of a prepositional phrase, in which case it needs to be followed by a noun and any associated modifiers.

I could imagine someone saying:

> We went to Paris for the holidays. Or
>   We went to Paris for my mother's health.

One way I could imagine someone combining "We went to Paris for" and "visiting the Louvre museum", would be the rather clumsy sentence:

> We went to Paris for the purpose of visiting the Louvre museum.